JOLT null values on array result
I have a large payload for a complex JOLT transformation spec that gives empty/null values in the end result. Since the input, spec, and output are quite big, I have provided pastebin links.
Could someone explain that null value on the result? How could i remove or don't create this?
INPUT
{
  "data": [
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:05:00",
      "TicketId": 49562693,
      "MedicionId": "80041",
      "utc": -6
    },
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:10:00",
      "TicketId": 49562693,
      "MedicionId": "80042",
      "utc": -6
    }
  ]
}

SPEC
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "val": "@(1,MedicionId)[&1].&",
          "fechaOffsetLocal": "@(1,MedicionId)[&1].&",
          "utc": "@(1,MedicionId)[&1].&"
        }
      },
      "TicketId": "TicketId"
    }
  }
]

Output
{
  "80041": [
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:05:00",
      "utc": -6
    }
  ],
  "80042": [
    null,
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:10:00",
      "utc": -6
    }
  ]
}


The indexes starts with 0 and increment by 1, eg. 0,1,2,3 ... The nulls (it's single in this case,might be multiple) complete the places of missing indexes. [&1] might be replaced with [0] in order to prevent index generation for this type of case such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "val|fechaOffsetLocal|utc": "@1,MedicionId[0].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

which will return the result
{
  "80041": [
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:05:00",
      "utc": -6
    }
  ],
  "80042": [
    {
      "val": 0,
      "fechaOffsetLocal": "2023-04-26T00:10:00",
      "utc": -6
    }
  ]
}

without nulls
